# ayuda syntaxError: unexpected token { in json at position 4

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

no se en donde sea el error, pero si hace la consulta bien

```
$.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'cargar/carga',
        type : "POST",
        data: {id:id},   
        success: function(json,textStatus, jqXHR) {  
          console.log(json);

            if (json.Status==true)
            {      

              $('#nombre').val(json.Data.nombre);
              $('#apellido').val(json.Data.apellido);
              $('#tel').val(json.Data.tel);
              $('#domicilio').val(json.Data.domicilio);

              $('#modal_persona').modal('show');
          console.log("Succs");
      }
      else{console.log("error");
      }
        },
        complete : function(jqXHR , textStatus) {

        },

        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log("complete error "+textStatus);
          console.log(jqXHR);
          console.log(errorThrown);
        },
        statusCode: {
             404: function() {
                  console.error( "page not found" );


             },
             500: function(){
                 console.log("Internal server error"); 
             }
         }

    });
```

controlador

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
    print_r($id);
    $data = $this->model->carga($id);
    if ($data) {

                    $this->output
                    ->set_content_type('application/json')
                    ->set_status_header(200)
                    ->set_output(json_encode(array(
                        "Status" => true,
                        "Message" => "GET",
                        "Data" =>  $data
                    )));
                }else
                {
                     $this->output
                    ->set_content_type('application/json')
                    ->set_status_header(500)
                    ->set_output(json_encode(array(
                        "Status" => false,
                        "Message" => "GET"

                    )));
                }
```

Comment: Muestra el texto del JSON que estás obteniendo, parece ser erróneo. Lo puedes validar en [**`jsonlint`**](https://jsonlint.com), pegándolo y pulsando en el botón `Validate JSON`
.

Comment: en el console.log(json) no me lo imprime, pero si imprimo json.status me pone true

Comment: En la petición Ajax agrega este parámetro: `dataType: "json",`, lo puedes poner por ejemplo después de `type : "POST",`, por cierto conviene usar `method`  en vez de `type`, o sea: `method : "POST",` a no ser que tengas un jQuery muyyy antiguo. En cuanto al `if`  puedes ponerlo así simplemente: `if (json.Status)
            {`  o bien usar la comparación estricta: `if (json.Status===true)
            {`

Comment: Ahhh otra cosa, el controlador no puede sacar nada por pantalla. Esto `print_r($id);` y cualquier otra cosa que saques por pantalla de forma arbitraria, va a fastidiar tu resultado.

Comment: gracias amigo, si era por el print_r, ya funciono

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando envías una petición Ajax que espera un JSON como en este caso, no puede salir por pantalla **nada más que un JSON**.

En el controlador tienes un código que te va a fastidiar la salida:

<s>`print_r($id);`</s>

Debes borrarlo.

También, puedes mejorar la petición Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'cargar/carga',
        method : "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {id:id},   
        success: function(json,textStatus, jqXHR) {  
          console.log(json);

            if (json.Status)
            {      

              $('#nombre').val(json.Data.nombre);
              //resto del código
```

Se recomienda usar `done` en vez de `success` y `fail` en vez de `error`. En un futuro `success` y `error` serán sacados del core de jQuery, por lo que estás usando código declarado obsoleto desde jQuery 3.